# Is it possible to boot Amazon Fire Phone with a vanilla build of Android Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, vanilla-android, amazon-fire-phone

I was wondering if it would be possible to run a vanilla Android Lollipop build on Amazon Fire phone. Google won't support it by default, but is there a patched version of the Lollipop ROM that could be used to run Android on it?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so because over Amazon Fire phone are working over their own version of Android based ROMs, not the Android ROMs. I don't think that there are chances you can go past !

Comment: But aren't there any patched ROMs like the Cyangen Mod that can work with it?

Comment: I am not sure on this which is the reason why I have posted my answer over the comments. Maybe we should wait a bit more while for other member to confirm this one out as I am afraid but I haven't tried doing anything like that before! :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, given the current fire phone offer, it'd be great to get hands on the hardware which is pretty good. Let's wait.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who has dreamed about Android on the Fire phone: It is possible. You can install CM11 (Android KitKat 4.4.X) on your device. The procedure is described here on XDA: [[ROM][STABLE] CM-11 for Safestrap v4 2015/08/10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/fire-phone/development/rom-cm-11-20150706-unofficial-t3151443)

There are some issues and bugs, but if you are interested in it, then go for it ;)

Fresh Installation

1. From Safestrap(the recovery you have to install), go into Wipe Menu and Swipe to perform a factory
   reset.
2. Flash the ROM File
3. Flash PA Gapps Modular PICO
4. Flash the latest SuperSU package if you want root
5. Reboot
6. Enjoy!